Can I use a brushed DC motor at higher-than-rated duty cycle at reduced load?
I have a linear actuator powered by a brushed DC motor which I got from an adjustable bed. The actuator label has the following information:

Input Voltage: 24V DC
Max Load: 6000N (Push)
Speed: 4.2mm/sec
Duty Cycle: 10%

I assume that the duty-cycle limit of 10% does not refer to a PWM duty-cycle, but rather to usage over the course of minutes. I've seen labels on similar motors that say something like "10% duty-cycle max: 2 minutes on, 18 minutes off". This makes me think that the limitation is primarily a thermal one.
My question is, can I go past the rated duty-cycle if I reduce the load on the motor? In the extreme case, could I potentially operate at 100% duty-cycle with no load? Unloaded, this motor draws about 350 mA at 24V. I haven't been able to measure the current draw under the full rated load of 6000N, but it must be over an amp to maintain 4.2mm/s.
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a datasheet for the motor, so I'm looking for guiding principles rather than firm answers for this specific motor. Reasonable assumptions and guesses are fine.

Yes, you can do that. The power dissipation in the motor is caused by its winding resistance, which means that it's proportional to the square of the current draw (I²R heating). The fact that the motor can run at maximum load with a duty cycle of 10% means that it can dissipate accumulated heat at 10% of the speed that it heats up at under full load. If the motor runs continuously, it'll still be fine as long as it outputs less thermal power than it can dissipate into its surroundings.
To cut the I²R losses down to 10% (0.1), you need to decrease the current through the motor by a factor of \$\sqrt{0.1}\$, which is around 0.3. This means that as long as the motor draws less than 30% of its maximum-load current, it theoretically shouldn't overheat. I'd drop that down to 20% for some safety margin and to account for mechanical losses as well.
You should of course also check the motor's temperature just to make sure it really is okay. Keep in mind that the leadscrew of the linear actuator might also heat up due to friction, so you should keep an eye on that as well, ideally with a thermal camera.
